# Git Bash and git in Powershell. Can I set a ssh config so both use the same key path?

Tags: bash, git, powershell, github

I can create a ssh key using git bash and it seems to work fine.I can use it and clone and push repos. However, the Git command in powershell works except for interactions with push, clone and pull.

I get this:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It appears to me that git bash is using the key from a K drive. It is a network drive and I would prefer both to pull my public key from the C drive conventional location. How can I set git bash to use the conventional location?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#standard-user

Comment: I did read that. It seems I need to know how to change git bash to use the same key as powershell. Powershell seems to use the right location, on C:

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement